# Compare two sheets in Excel and extract the differences to other third sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

My situation: 
I got a huge excel sheet from a manufacturer of products for my online shop. This format:

```
product ID | price | name | ...
```

Every week the manufacturer is sending me a updated list with new products. So I need to know which products are new in that list. So what I need is a code snippet, which does the following:

- I´m gonna insert the old product list in sheet1 (manually)
- I´m gonna insert the new product list in sheet2 (manually)
- Compare the product IDs of Sheet1 and Sheet2
- Insert the products (rows) from the new list (Sheet2) in Sheet3, which are not present in the old list (Sheet1)

So the result in Sheet3 would be all new products.
I hope you can push me in the right direction.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think You might need something like this:
`=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1:A100,Sheet2!A1:F100,6,FALSE)`

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396677/excel-compare-two-cell-from-different-sheet-if-true-copy-value-from-other-cell

Of course You can also solve this, using VBA with buttons and all kind of fancy things.

Comment: Did You manage to solve the problem? If yes, remember to accept the best answer as a solution. If You have more questions, feel confident to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'd do it a different way altogether using the PowerQuery addin from Microsoft but I don't know how well it works on Excel 2010 (it wouldn't work on Excel 2007). With that you can do append queries with grouping on you product ID so that you get a unique list.

The other way to do it is to keep the sheets in different files and use the Excel query tool to do a join query on the two tables into a new table.

Either way, once you have your new table, you save it out in readiness for the next merge.

Answer (score 0):

In `Sheet2` (updated item), add a column D that checks if the product is new:

```
=MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)>0
```

Add a column E that gives the `TRUE` values in column D a unique identifier

```
=D5&COUNTIF(D$2:D2)
```

Now go to `Sheet3` (the new items) and put an index column in, say, column E with values `TRUE1`, `TRUE2`, `TRUE3` and so on, as many as you think you'll ever need (e.g. if one day there are 20 new items and you only went up to `TRUE15`, then you're going to miss 5 items).

You can then bring in the new items with:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH($E2,Sheet2!$E:$E,0))
```